# how create dynamic template with directive attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I create a directive, and want to use dynamic template with attribute `wm.data.typeName`.

```
wm.data.typeName = "<span>html code</span>"

<fill-choose model-input="wm.data.modelInput" text="wm.data.typeName"></fill-choose>
```

and **directive fillChoose** is

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('learn')
    .directive('fillChoose', fillChoose);

  /** @ngInject */
  function fillChoose($showdown) {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: function(elem, attr) {
        //return $showdown.makeHtml(fill.modelInput);
        return '<div>'+ attr.modelInput +'</div>';
      },
      scope: {
        modelInput: '=',
        text: '='
      },
      controller: FillChooseController,
      controllerAs: 'fill',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function FillChooseController($scope) {
      var vm = this;
    }
  }

})();
```

But in this way, template will be `<div>wm.data.modelInput</div>`.

How to make the template be `<div><span>html code</span></div>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
    //return $showdown.makeHtml(fill.modelInput);
    elem.html($compile('<div>{{fill.modelInput}}</div>')(scope));
  }
```

Now for this very case a simple

```
template:'<div>{{fill.modelInput}}</div>';
```

Would work, but i gave the $compile thing because you may gave only a simplified version of what you're really trying to do.

Comment: In your way I got

&lt;div&gt;html code&lt;/div&gt;

not

<div>html code</div>

then make a filter use $sce.trustAsHtml , but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

you have to print it

```
<fill-choose model-input="{{ wm.data.modelInput }}" text="wm.data.typeName"></fill-choose>
```

but this will work **once**, because template function will call **once**, when directive is initialized (**when angular calles compile to compile template**), that's why you need to pass it through directive's **scope**